# VBA Can't save Access Form via Excel

Tags: excel, vba, forms, ms-access, output

I tried to connect my Excel to Access via VBA. And I managed to connect to my Access Form
but when I try to save it, it doesn't work.

```
...
Set conn = CreateObject("Access.Application")
conn.OpenCurrentDatabase conPath

On Error GoTo ende
    conn.DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_test", acFormDS, "", "", , acNormal
    conn.Forms![frm_test]![Year] = year
    conn.Forms![frm_test]![Status] = "open"
    conn.DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, "frm_test", acFormatXLS, , True
```

When I execute the code it opens the explorer window and I can choose where to save the file.
But when I click on save there is no file and no file is open afterwards.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by 'save'? The code is opening form and trying to output data to workbook, not save form.

Comment: Don't even need to open form to export data. However, I tested your code (without the year and "open" lines) and it works. Where do you click "Save", I see "OK" and "Cancel". Why export to a new workbook, why not pull data from Access with SQL instead?

Comment: Are Year and Status UNBOUND textboxes?

Comment: You should disable the On Error line and debug your code. Show your code for declaring and cleaning up the Access object variable.

Comment: I tested with the AutoStart argument as False and code works.